# SWIG doesn't expand macro definition

Tags: c#, c++, swig, c-preprocessor

I need to wrap some `C++` classes to use it from managed `C#` application.

I have:

SWIG interface file:

```
%module mylib
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "foo.h"
```

`foo.h`:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#define _X(x) x
#define _Y _X

 /* line 6 */    _Y(void) dummy();

#endif // FOO_H
```

`foo.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"
_Y(void) dummy() { }
```

SWIG fails to generate wrapper with message: `foo.h(6): Error: Syntax error in input(1)`.

It seems that SWIG doesn't substitute `_X(x)` with `x`.

**Is there any workaround?**

**UPD1**
[Here](https://gist.github.com/evgeny-t/ae0e5d0be8ee981391ac) is exactly what is run.
SWIG command line is: `swig -csharp -c++ int.i`.

It throws `foo.h(7) : Error: Syntax error in input(1).`

If I replace `#define _Y _X` with `#define _Y(x) _X(x)` it works fine. It's ok but in real case I'm not able to change header files because its are thirdparty.

Comment: This is somewhat surprising. The code you posted is exactly what you are running? It seems to be a cleaned up version for posting, which is good but make sure to try SWIG on it to ensure you still get that issue you are describing.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? :\

Comment: @jtlz2 unfortunately, no, I gave up 5 years ago :)